# Cut and fail semantics in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

What does the following code do?

```
not(P) :- P, !, fail.
not(P).
```

And how does that work differently from the following 2 codes :

```
not(P) :- P, !, fail.
not(P) :- P, !.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the trees:

[image: trees]

## First Program (inverses the success value of `P`)

### If the call to `P` succeeds:

1. Enter predicate not(P)
2. Enter clause 1 of predicate not(P)
3. Call(P) --> **Success**
4. Traverse Cut
5. Call Fail --> **Failure**
6. Try to backtrack to find alternate solutions
7. There is a Cut in the way of backtracking; exit the whole predicate with **Failure** (The Cut+Fail force failure of the predicate if P succeeds)

### If the call to `P` fails:

1. Enter predicate not(P)
2. Enter clause 1 of predicate not(P)
3. Call(P) --> **Failure**
4. Clause 1 results in --> **Failure**
5. Try alternate clause 2
6. Call True --> **Success**
7. There is nothing more to do; exit the predicate with **Success**

## Second Program (always fails)

### If the call to `P` succeeds:

Behaviour is exactly the same as for the First Program, exit the whole predicate with **Failure**.

### If the call to `P` fails:

1. Enter predicate not(P)
2. Enter clause 1 of predicate not(P)
3. Call(P) --> **Failure**
4. Clause 1 results in --> **Failure**
5. Try alternate clause 2
6. Call(P) --> **Failure**
7. There is nothing more to do; exit the predicate with **Failure**. Actually there is a cut to traverse still but it doesn't do anything.

## Trying Program 1

Note that `not/1` is already a built-in, but I guess we can override it for this exercise.

```
?- [user].
|: not(P) :- P, !, fail.
|: not(P).

Warning: user://1:9:
Warning:    Singleton variables: [P]
|: % user://1 compiled 0.02 sec, 2 clauses
true.
```

Okay

```
?- not(true).
false.

?- not(false).
true.
```

Looks good.

## Trying Program 2

```
?- [user].
|: not(P) :- P, !, fail.
|: not(P) :- P, !.    
|: % user://1 compiled 0.02 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- not(true).
false.

?- not(false).
false.
```

Looks good.

Comment: is not(p) used as a procedure here or else as a keyword? and what do you mean by sucess and failure of call to p ?(the bold highlighted ones)

Comment: @sai_varshittha. `not(P)` is a predicate - you call it, passing it some term `P`. If `P` later appears in a clause at predicate position (generally in between `,`, as here, instead of enclosed by a function symbol as in `f(P)`) Prolog regards it a an expression to be executed. For example, `not(member(1,[1,2])` will result in a call to `member(1,[1,2])`, which succeeds. `not(false)` will result in a call to `false`, which fails. `not(foo)` will result in a call to `foo`, which is not defined as a predicate and cause an exception.

Comment: I am getting the following results ,
`?- not(member(1,[1,2])).
false.`
`?- not(false).
false.`

`?- not(true).
false.`

So is the result always false? And why is it so?